# Why not let the `instanceid` of `opampextension` directly use the value of `service.instance.id`?

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

`opampextension` currently does the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QbKz.png)

"I have a question: Since the `instanceid` of `opampextension` uniquely identifies the OTEL agent, and `service.instance.id` also represents an OTEL agent, why doesn't `opampextension` directly read the value of `service.instance.id`, but instead sets a separate configuration item for it?"

If the values of `opampextension`'s `instanceid` and `service.instance.id` are inconsistent, the connection between `opampextension` and self-monitoring metrics needs to be identified by (`service.instance.id`, `instanceid`).

Keeping them consistent would simplify the connection between the two.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the OpAMP specification](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opamp-spec/blob/main/specification.md#agenttoserverinstance_uid) the instance id from the agent must be a ULID whereas the collector's instance id is a UUID. The code you linked shows that an instance ID can be provided by the configuration, otherwise it is read from the collector's `service.instance.id` property ([which is a UUID](https://github.com/open-telemetry/semantic-conventions/blob/5a94098c2a80417f4d5bde58ed470314290ed7da/docs/resource/README.md?plain=1#L115-L119)). A server receiving the ULID can disaggregate the ULID into a timestamp and a UUID ([sample code](https://github.com/oklog/ulid/pull/92/files#diff-5d278b8b241ca71f70d4868a0140903478027e080bcc0c87525db42aaebc9066R289-R303)). If you have more questions, please raise an issue in the [collector-contrib repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib) or the [opamp-go repository](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opamp-go/). You can also ask any questions in the #otel-agentmanwg channel in the CNCF slack. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

In OTEL's `opampsupervisor` component, the `instanceid` and `service.instance.id` are kept consistent. But in `opampextension`, they are not made consistent, and I don't understand why it is designed this way.

Consider this scenario: I want to query the self-monitoring metrics of the corresponding OTEL agent, but I only know the `instanceid`, not the `service.instance.id`. If the values of the two are different, then I won't be able to make the query.

Comment: I have already raised an [issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/32034) in the repository, thank you.